# Couldn't find Comment without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am building a basic website with forum functionality.  I am trying to implement a feature in the PostController#Show that will display each comment associated with that post.  However, I keep getting an error along the lines of Can't Find ______ Without An ID.  Here is what I have:

## Posts Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.find(params[:post_id])
  end
```

I have tried multiple variations for @comments, but similar errors occur.

## Post Show View

```
<h1><%= markdown_to_html @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> age by
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <p><%= markdown_to_html( @post.body) %></p>
    <p><%= markdown_to_html( @comments ) %></p>
    </div
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn     btn-success' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
    end
  end


  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
  get 'contact' => 'welcome#contact'

  root to: 'welcome#index'


end
```

I assume this has something to do with nesting Comments within Posts within Topics and not using the correct syntax.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do, in your view:

`@post.comments.each do |comment|`

Alternatively in your controller:

`@comments = @post.comments`

I'm assuming you have an association set up.

Comment: You're correct, I used your first method.  Newbie mistake. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Happens to everyone.